# Set row height of a UITableView according to the cell in that row

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to adjust the row height of a UITableView according to the cell in that row.

Initially, I tried to use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, the problem is, when the table is loading, the calling flow is seemed to be:

First call:

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then call:

```
(UIViewTableCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which means, before my cell is generated, I have to tell the table the height of its row.

However, what I want is exactly the opposite, i.e., after my cell is generated, I tell the table the height of this rows.

Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: Yes it is possible . Just imagine the **chat View** , Which has dynamically loading and the data . Here the Cell is loading according to the data . You need to calculate the size before entering into the cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: you want that for each row? or a size for every row?

Comment: you can calculate the height of each cell if you know each one's content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an array of heights for every row based on the data from `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and in the `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:` just take the height value from that array.

Declare in your implementation file:

```
NSMutableArray *heights;
```

In `viewDidLoad:` initialise it:

```
heights = [NSMutableArray array];
```

In `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set the height for each row:

```
[heights addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:HEIGHT]];
```

And in the `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:` return required height:

```
return [heights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This should work because `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for every cell and then for every cell `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

Comment: yes this is what i write before but for each cell with different size

Comment: to me the problem is that tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: is called before then tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @MirkoCatalano how did you solve your problem? i have the same now

Comment: How can this work when heightForRow is called before cellForRow?

Answer (score 1):

may be the only solution is make a variable into the .h file like

`@property (nonatomic) int height`

initialise it into the viewDidLoad like

```
self.height = 40;
```

and then return this variable into the

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 return self.height;
}
```

then in your `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` update this variable like your new height and then reload the `[self.yourTable reloadData]` in your `viewDidAppear`

Comment: looking for working solution for the same problem. In my case cell contents are dynamic.